# Pivot Table query from SQL tables gives error - sometimes

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

Running Excel 2010 with PowerPivot 10.50.1747.0, accessing SQL Server 2005 SP2.

I am modifying an Excel pivot table. It gets its data from a SQL table, via a query.  I am making changes to the query under "Table Properties."  When I enter my new query, and click the "Validate" button, I get "The SQL statement is valid."  If I click the "Design" button and in the resulting window click the Run ("!") button, I get the proper data.  BUT, when I get out of the Design window and click the Save button, I get the error:

```
==============
The refresh operation failed because the source data base or the table does 
not exist, or because you do not have access to the source

More Details:
OLE DB or ODBC error.
An error occurred while processing the 'Query' table.
The operation has been cancelled.
==============
```

What is going on here?  (I am using a table variable - would that be causing the problem?)  Thanks for any assistance.

Here is the code:

```
declare @WCsWithDups TABLE(  
 WOStatus Char(1) not null,  
 WOCreated DateTime not null,  
 WorkOrderNo VarChar(15) not null,  
 WorkCenterID VarChar(6) not null,  
 ItemClassID VarChar(12) not null,  
 StockItem Char(1) not null,  
 FirstChar Char(1) not null,  
 MaxWODays SmallInt not null  
)  

insert into @WCsWithDups(WOStatus, WOCreated, WorkOrderNo, WorkCenterID, ItemClassID, StockItem, FirstChar, MaxWODays)  
select DISTINCT  
case 
 when wocompleted is null then 'O' 
 else 'C' end as WOstatus, 
wocreated, 
WorkOrderNo, 
workcenterid, 
itemclassid, 
case when timinventory.minstockqty>0 then 'Y' 
 when timinventory.maxstockqty>0 then 'Y' 
 when timinventory.safetystockqty>0 then 'Y' 
 when timinventory.stdordqty>0 then 'Y' 
 else 'N' end as stockitem, 
left(itemproduced,1) as FirstChar,
(select  max(datediff(day,wocreated,transdate)+1) from vdvMT b where TR1.workorderno=b.workorderno) as maxwodays

from vdvMT as TR1
 left join tInv on TR1.itemkeyproduced=tInv.itemkey and TR1.whsekey=tInv.whsekey
where type='L' and wocreated>=(getdate()-365) and (workcenterid = 'Shed' or workcenterid = 'OP') 

delete from @WCsWithDups
where WorkOrderNo in (
 select WorkOrderNo from @WCsWithDups group by WorkOrderNo having count(WorkOrderNo) = 1);

select distinct WOStatus, WOCreated, WorkOrderNo, 'Shed+OP' as WorkCenterID, ItemClassID, StockItem, FirstChar, MaxWODays 
from @WCsWithDups
```

Comment: The error message formatting got a little messed up - the first bunch of equal signs was meant to be an opening delimiter; the error ends after "...been cancelled." (Don't know why that text is larger than the rest...)

Comment: Can you paste the SQL code that this generates into your question? That would really help.

Comment: Ok, I edited my orig post to include the problem code.

Comment: If you run SQL Server Profiler what actually happens when you click the "Save" button? What queries does it send to the server?

Comment: OK - finally ran it (busy day here).  I don't see anything "odd" in the profiler, although I'm not sure what precisely I should be looking for.  For starters, the first trace item begins with: declare @p1 int
set @p1=0
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,NULL,N'<insert the whole code here>',1
select @p1 ==============  Ok, that's it.  The next event contains the exact query.  There are 44 rows of events in total for this "Save" action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was scanning unanswered questions - looks like the OP got this one was answered elsewhere:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel/thread/d7c7bc25-d140-4957-9b66-9963d1c655b1

Set No Count ON before Insert and Set No Count OFF after insert

> PowerPivot supports only one recordset
>   in your case by executing insert and
>   delete you will get multiple result
>   sets which could be the problem.